# C adding to struct pointer array doesnt work in function

Tags: c

I have a struct Student. I initialise it inside the main function, and i try to add students inside a function. It doesn't work, but if i put the same code into the main function, it works normally. What am i doing wrong?

```
struct Student
{
    char* name;
};

void addStudent(struct Student *student, int *n)
{
    (*n)++;
    if(*n != 1)
    {
        student = realloc(student, (*n) * sizeof(struct Student));
    }

    printf("Insert name : ");
    student[*n-1].name = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", student[*n-1].name);

    for(int i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        printf("name: %s\n", student[i].name);
    }
}
```

main:

```
int main() {
    int n=0;
    struct Student *student = malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Student));

    while(1)
    {
        addStudent(student, &n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @infinitezero it breaks after the first time `realloc` moves the data, because the reassigned pointer is local to `addStudent`.

Comment: When you assign to `student` inside `addStudent` that is only inside of that function. After control leaves that function the global variable is unchanged. If the call to `realloc` moves the memory area this also causes undefined behaviour on any subsequent access to the global `student`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: You need your argument to be of `struct Student **` since you are using `malloc()`/`realloc()` inside a function.

---

As you are aware, when an argument is passed in a function, its value is copied so that any changes made inside the function will not be visible to the calling code. We overcome this by passing a pointer to the value we want to modify: we do not change the actual value of our argument, we are only messing with the memory location our pointer argument points to.

In your code, you are reallocating space inside your function, which means that the value of the pointer *itself* is modified. So, this change is "discarded" after the end of the function and your main never sees the reallocated pointer (note that the allocated space is still "there", meaning that your program takes that resource, you have just no pointer referencing it after the end of your function which is a memory leak).

The solution: make the argument of type *pointer* to the *pointer* you want to reallocate, i.e. `struct Student **`.

The changes you need to do are the following:

```c
void addStudent(struct Student **pstudent, int *n) {
    (*n)++;
    if(*n != 1){
        *pstudent = realloc(*pstudent, (*n) * sizeof(struct Student));
    }
    (*pstudent)[*n-1].name = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", (*pstudent)[*n-1].name);

    for(int i=0;i<*n;i++)
    {
        printf("name: %s\n", (*pstudent)[i].name);
    }
}
```

and in your `main()` just call your function as:

```c
    addStudent(&student, &n);
```

Comment: I have tried doing that, but then i get a SIGSEGV error (exit code 139)

Comment: the error happens at 
student[*n-1]->ime = malloc (25 * sizeof(char))

Comment: Have a look at the answer now (the code has been edited to include the rest of the lines from your function, modified appropriately). I failed to copy the whole function in my first answer due to indentation. Note that the parentheses around the name of the array are necessary to denote that the pointer goes to the pointer of the array and not to the `[*n-1]`-th element